# What should be in database.yml to use rails without database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I am using rails3 without database and wondering what should be in database.yml to pass  rake test.
It fails now. I didn't specify anything in the file yet. My models are going to use ActiveModel.

```
class User

  # https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
...

end
```

Running rake test:

```
runtime/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/memory_test_fix-0.1.3/lib/memory_test_fix.rb:29:in `in_memory_database?': undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the following must be in application.rb:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Instead of

```
require 'rails/all'
```

Comment: Disable all active_record references in config/environments/*.rb as well.

Comment: require "active_resource/railtie" is not needed for Rails 7

Answer (score 0):

remove active record from your environment.rb

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]
```

Comment: This is the rails2 way to do that

Comment: No prob, however I still have some problems with this. I am going to investigate more the issue, how to use ActiveModel and disable ActiveRecord.